# GCC consumes too much Memory!! graph-tool

Tags: c++, gcc, graph-tool

While Compiling [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/download#arch) the gcc-compiler consumes more than 7 Gb of memory and after consuming more and more nothing happens anymore and I am forced to stop the compilation. I tried to embed [a compiler suffix](http://hostingfu.com/article/compiling-with-gcc-on-low-memory-vps):

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS --param ggc-min-expand=0 --param ggc-min-heapsize=8192"
```

but I wasnt able to bring it into the ./configure procedure. Anyone knows of this issue? (It shouldn't make a difference but my OS is Archlinux-64)

Edit (1): I was able to add now the CFLAGS to configure, but it continues to consume an infinite number of memory. My Gcc Version is 4.8.2!

**Edit (2): New Version of graph-tool (2.2.28) solved my problem because they fixed this [memory issue](http://git.skewed.de/graph-tool/commit/?id=dbc89569d68a8724284259e63ce7b6fc57fe8d02)!!**

Comment: You can tell `configure` to call the C compiler with specific options by setting the `CFLAGS` environment variable like this: `./configure CFLAGS="-foo bar --baz"`

Comment: which version of gcc are you using?

Comment: Did you try to force the virtual memory usage, with something like:
ulimit -v vmemsize

Comment: friol: Yes I did, but He just tells me then that not enough memory is available for compiling!

Comment: Just to note, because graph-tool uses lots of metaprograming (template classes), it does a lot during compile time, and is fast on runtime. I'm just confirming that the amount of memory you are observing that the gcc is taking, is normal, and it's what it is on all the systems. That's why they have binaries for many distros, cause if you want to compile it for yourself, you need that amount of memory.

Comment: Are you doing any parallel building (`make -j`)?

Answer (score 1):

7 GB is too much... You should need around 4 GB with GCC 4.8. Could it be you are compiling in parallel (with make -j)?